# Fundamental vector field on a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, lie-groups, vector-fields

We know that in general if M is a manifold provided with an action of a lie group G, then for X in the Lie algebra of G , we define the vector field $X_M$  by

$X_M(m) = \frac{d}{dt}_{|t=0}e^{-tX}.m $.

I've come across this statement wich I don't know how to prove it:

Let V be a euclidean vector space of dimension n with basis $e_i$, $1 \leq i \leq n$. We denote by $x_i$ the coordinate functions on V, and $\partial_i $ the direvation in the direction of the vector $e_i$.
Suppose that V is provided with an action of a Lie group G.

Why this is true:

If $X \in \mathfrak{g}$,  then the vector field $X_V$ is given by :

$X_V= - \sum_{i < j} (Xe_i,e_j)(x_i \partial_j - x_j \partial_i)$ ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't true. For example, take $V=\mathbb{R}^2$, $G=\operatorname{GL}(2,\mathbb{R})$, and $X = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\in\mathfrak{g}$. Then
$$
X_V(x_1,x_2) = \frac{d}{dt}\Big\vert_{t=0}\begin{pmatrix} e^{-t} & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2\end{pmatrix} = \frac{d}{dt}\Big\vert_{t=0}\begin{pmatrix}e^{-t}x_1 \\ x_2\end{pmatrix} = -x_1\partial_1,
$$
but according to your formula it would be
$$
X_V(x_1,x_2) = -(Xe_1,e_1)(x_1\partial_2-x_2\partial_1) = -(x_1\partial_2-x_2\partial_1).
$$
Perhaps the statement you read has some additional conditions on the group $G$?

Comment: thank you  so much for pointing that. Indeed, you're right,  I just verify the statement and I find that G is  a closed subgroup of SO(V).

Comment: In this case, you should use the fact that $\mathfrak{so}(V)$ has a basis of vectors of the form $\{X_{ij} = E_{ij}-E_{ji} \mid i<j\}$, where $E_{ij}$ denotes the matrix of with 1 in the $ij$th position and zero elsewhere. You can check from the definition that the fundamental vector field $(X_{ij})_V$ associated with $X_{ij}$ is $x_i\partial_j -x_j\partial_i$. Writing $X = \sum_{i<j} a_{ij}X_{ij}$ should then give the result (although I think the coefficient should be $\pm(Xe_i,e_j)$, not $(Xe_i,e_i)$, which is always zero for $X\in\mathfrak{so}(V)$.)

Comment: I'm sorry that was a typo it's $-(Xe_i,e_j)$ rather than $(Xe_i,e_i )$, I'll fix that. And thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Glad it was helpful!